# What should be the server configuration for Magento 1.9?

Tags: database, server-setup, system-configuration

What should be the `server configuration` for Magento 1.9 which can handle **70k** `Configurable products` and **500k** `simple products`? Also 4000 users at a time on website

Comment: Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thanks Aditya for your answer. Do you have checked it on live /running website ?

Comment: Yes this is Authenticate data from Magento itself and some of live projects are running perfectly fine which have huge Database..

Comment: The question i needed to answer was: can Magento support this level of traffic
and how much would it cost to run?

Comment: By flexing a little of the knowledge and experience, could match and indeed exceed these performance requirements with fairly moderate hardware requirements.

Comment: A standard Magento demo store is capable of delivering roughly 230 uniques per GHz, per hour.